# docker-compose mounted volume empty

Tags: docker, docker-compose, dockerfile

For some reason, my target directory is still empty. `/root/temp` is present in the container, but it's empty. Is it not possible to copy files from a host directory onto a container with docker-compose?

My project directory looks like this:

```
+ app/
|-- docker-compose.yml
|-- Dockerfile-flask
|-- requirements.txt
|-- app.py
|-- temp/
|-- -- hello.txt
```

This is my docker-compose file:

```
version: "3.5"

services:

    flask: 
        image: webapp-flask
        container_name: flask_cnr
        build:
            context: .
            dockerfile: Dockerfile-flask
        restart: always
        volumes: 
            - ./temp/hello.txt:/root/temp/hello.txt
```

And this is my Dockerfile-flask:

```
FROM python:3.6
RUN mkdir /app
WORKDIR /app
EXPOSE 5000
COPY requirements.txt .

RUN apt-get update \
    && apt-get install -y --no-install-recommends python-setuptools=33.1.1-1 python-pip=9.0.1-2 \
    python-wheel=0.29.0-2 libpython-dev=2.7.13-2 \
    && apt-get clean \
    && rm -rf /var/lib/apt/lists/*

RUN apt-get update &&\
    apt-get -y install gcc mono-mcs &&\
    apt-get -y install curl &&\
    apt-get -y install vim &&\
    apt-get -y install python-yaml &&\
    rm -rf /var/lib/apt/lists/*

RUN pip install -r requirements.txt
COPY . .
CMD ["python","app.py"]
```

Why is hello.txt not being created in `root/temp`?

Comment: What does the dockerfile look like?

Comment: Can you edit the question to have your YAML file, rather than a picture of it?

Comment: I think it is related to the file permission of `app/temp`. Do you insert any `USER` command in your flask docker file? And what is your `app/temp` dir permission? Which user do you use to run `docker-compose`?

Comment: Na, it needs the trailing slash, `- ./temp/:/root/temp`

Comment: I edited the docker-compose.yml file to have the trailing slash but it doesn't solve the problem. `/root/temp` is still empty. I've included my Dockerfile-flask. I did chmod 777 to `app/temp` but it's still mounting an empty volume.

Comment: I tried it and it works with and without trailing slash. I still think you might be checking the wrong path inside the container. Can you try and mount the file directly? (- ./temp/hello.txt:/root/temp/hello.txt) This should definitely work. If it doesn't maybe try changing the /root/temp location.

Comment: I tried to mount the file directly and hello.txt becomes a directory (in the container)

Comment: Figured it out, I'm using the WSL so the linux directories I provided weren't mapping to any files. Using the windows paths fixed it